# Python split words but letters returned instead

Tags: python, split

I want to split this text into words but split() keeps returning me letters instead of whole words.

```
f="""Police have seized fake money being used to buy goods in ALAWA. An 
investigation is underway to locate where it came from. It's understood 50 
dollar notes with Chinese symbols have emerged at a Woolworths, butcher 
and bottle shop."""
words = set(line.strip() for line in f)
print(words)
```

This is the output I received:

```
{'', 'u', 's', 'l', '(', 'o', 'D', 't', '3', '/', 'I', 'C', 'T', '1', '-', '+', 'i', '6', '0', 'g', 'Q', '8', 'M', 'm', 'z', 'y', '4', 'O', 'v', '2', ':', 'U', 'f', 'B', 'w', 'L', 'V', 'a', 'S', 'k', "'", '5', 'R', '•', 'p', 'P', 'e', 'X', 'd', 'b', 'n', 'r', 'A', 'W', ',', '7', '9', ')', 'c', 'h', 'N', '.', '&'}
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You never called `split()`. You called `strip()`

Comment: Call f.split(" ") and you are fine, then it splits on whitespaces.

Comment: perfect answer @DanielLee. Use split(). It uses whitespace as default delimiter.

Comment: `for line in f` is iterating through each letter, not word.

Comment: Normally the system automatically deletes "typo" questions after a couple of days, but we'll have to delete this one manually because it has upvoted answers, and those answers also prevent you from deleting it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply write:

```
words = set(f.split()) #you have used strip instead of split
```

Answer (score 4):

`line.strip()` will transverse through each character one by one. The method strip() returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the beginning and the end of the string. You should be using `split()` which splits string into list of strings by spaces in between.

Answer (score 2):

> words = set(line.strip() for line in f)

You think you might be looking at lines here, but actually you are looping over a giant string. In Python you are able to iterate over a string and it will return to you a list of all the characters that make up that string.

Also, the strip function only removes certain characters from the beginning and end of a string https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip . In your case, since you omitted any paramater, it will simply remove all leading and trailing spaces.

You can use the split function https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split with a space as argument to achieve what you want instead.

Comment: You make a good point in your 1st paragraph, but the 2nd isn't quite accurate. `.strip` just removes matching chars at the start and end of the string, not interior ones. Of course, that's irrelevant here since it's being passed strings that contain a single char.

Comment: Also, `.split()` is generally better than `.split(' ')`. The latter splits on single space chars, but the former splits on any runs of all whitespace chars.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: Good points, well made. I will adjust my reaction.